# SQL Update Column

Tags: sql, sql-update

How do I grab the last character of a column and convert it to a number? Example:
 Column
000000000017A
000000000038B
000000000431C
Need to change the last letter to the following if letter equals to:
A=1
B= 2
C=3
Results:
171
382
4313

Comment: Which RDBMS? What have you tried?

Comment: @PeterLang Used `SELECT REPLACE(Prev_Month_Vol,'A','1')
FROM table1`  works, but need to change the remaining letters like 'B' and 'C' to 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to use REPLACE function of SQL

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms186862.aspx

Comment: @Alex I've used the following REPLACE Statement and it worked, but it only replaced the letter 'A', how do I replace the remaining letters that are 'B' & 'C' into one SQL Statement?  `SELECT REPLACE(Amount,'A','1')
FROM table1`

Comment: @Alexz I figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

The ASCII value of `A` is 65.  So you can translate `C` to `3` by subtracting 64 from its ASCII value.

```
select  cast(
            left(col1, len(col1) - 1) +
            cast(ascii(upper(right(col1, 1))) - 64 as char(1))
            as int)
from    Table1
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c88f0/11/0)

Comment: Column1 contains over 300 records with the last character as a letter. How can convert the letters into numbers depending on the ending letters?

Comment: So there are also rows which end with a number?

Comment: Column1 only ends in letter. The other columns are fine.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  What do you expect this answer to do that it currently doesn't do?

Comment: Change all the ending letters to a number on Column1. Example SQL Statement  `SELECT REPLACE(Column1,'A','1')
FROM table1`  Works, but need to also change the remaining letters B & C. Hope this helps.

Comment: I figured it our. Thanks you for your help.

Comment: i don't know how his solution is easier than yours @Andomar, but to each his own apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with the following SQL Statement. To change multiple criteria replace in one column, I used:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Prev_Month_Vol,'A','1'), 'B', '2'), 'C', '3')
FROM table1
```

Hope this helps out someone looking to do replace statements.